# Google Analytics event being sent, but not received

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Basic setup: I have my `index.html` page, the usual Google code snippet before the `<head>` tag ends, and in one of my react-components.js files I have the following:

```js
ga('send','event','Comments','view','mainListItem');
```

I'm using Google Analytics plugin for dev tools, and it seems to confirm that I'm sending the event just fine. I also put in a callback in the send code, and it called back fine too. I am sending this from my test server at home (localhost), but it registered my activity on the realtime tracking page whenever I refresh the page, so why not the event? Also, it's been about half an hour/hour since the events were sent; not sure if they'd only show up after 24 hours or something. Here's what dev tools shows me:

```js
Account ID               : UA-XXXXXXX-Y // not actually X in the code.
Page Title               : Disqus Comments
Host Name                : disqus.com
Page                     : /embed/comments/?base=default&version=4aca534a0baee76617eb115212993522&f=mtg-hunter&t_i=382866&t_u=http%253A%252F%252Fmtg-hunter.com%252F%253Fq%253DBlack%2520Lotus%2523!newthread&t_e=Black%2520Lotus&t_d=MtG%253A%2520Hunter&t_t=Black%2520Lotus&t_c=4523863&s_o=default
Referring URL            : http://localhost:3333/
Hit ID                   : 1092606028
Hit Type                 : event
Event Name               : next
Event Type               : view_embed
Event Label              : mtg-hunter
Event Value              : 1
Visitor ID               : 1810044494
Session Count            : 2
Session Time - First     : Fri May 20 2016 20:04:12 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)
Session Time - Last      : Fri May 20 2016 20:04:12 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)
Session Time - Current   : Fri May 20 2016 21:16:42 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)
Campaign Time            : Fri May 20 2016 21:16:42 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)
Campaign Session         : 2
Campaign Count           : 2
Campaign Source          : localhost:3333
Campaign Medium          : referral
Campaign Name            : (referral)
Campaign Content         : /;
Custom Var 1             : label:'component' value:'embed' scope:'Page'
Custom Var 2             : label:'package' value:'free' scope:'Page'
Custom Var 3             : label:'forum' value:'mtg-hunter' scope:'Page'
Custom Var 4             : label:'version' value:'next' scope:'Page'
Custom Var 5             : label:'userType' value:'not_logged_in' scope:'Page'
Language                 : en-us
Encoding                 : UTF-8
Flash Version            : 21.0 r0
Java Enabled             : false
Screen Resolution        : 1920x1080
Browser Size             : 737x384
Color Depth              : 24-bit
Ga.js Version            : 5.6.7d
Cachebuster              : 1520316656
```

And yet, the Event report is completely blank. I'm using a view which isn't filtering my IP (anymore, which is why I see myself refreshing the page in the realtime report), so that's not the issue. I'm in the process of adding events to important parts of my code, and I was hoping to test them before making the code live, but maybe I'll only get results when it's live users sending the events?

Comment: Google (and me) recommend you to move to Google Tag Manager. This feature is new since 2013.

Comment: This is not your event in the dev tools. You are sending an event via universal analytics, which does not use ga.js and does not have custom dimensions. Also your values you've set for the event are not in that call , and I presume your domain name is not disqus.com - so this seems to originate from an embedded comment field  rather than your own code.

Comment: For testing purposes, use realtime monitoring to test your events.
Hope this helps!